# Creating a hover tooltip for SVG elements, using only html and css

Tags: html, css, svg, tooltip

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWwfy.png)So I am trying to create an interactive map. I have all layers in Illustrator and have exported to SVG. The layers are just grouped elements together from Illustrator, like the map outline, the facilities, the meeting rooms ect. 
I am studying graphic design so I only know the basics of html and css, nothing else.

The feature I am trying to work on is a tooltip with the name of the facility that pops up when you hover over it. I have included a short code of what the svg group looks like with just the circles.

I have learned how to make a tooltip for an icon image. 
I have had no luck with the SVG. Just looking for a simple solution as all research i have done ends up with javascript.

`

```
<g id="facilites">
<circle class="st2" cx="420.25" cy="333.25" r="25.25"/>

<circle class="st2" cx="666.25" cy="470.25" r="25.25"/>

</g>
```

Goal:Tooltip with name to appear when svg is hovered over

Comment: Add title elements containing the tooltip text as children of the elements you wish to provide tooltips for.

Comment: @RobertLongson  Hi Robert, thanks for the reply! Would you mind showing me quickly where it would go in the code?                                                        <g id="facilites">
 <circle class="st2" cx="420.25" cy="333.25" r="25.25"/>
 
 <circle class="st2" cx="666.25" cy="470.25" r="25.25"/>
 
  </g>

Comment: Please insert your code into the question. It will be easier for us to help you. Links can become inactive over time.

Comment: @CosminStaicu i have updated it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** After reading your answer again I think I might have misunderstood what you were asking.

If each circle is supposed to have its own tooltip then the following code is correct but if the tooltip content is the same and is supposed to work when you hover any part of the SVG element then the code at the bottom is the correct one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000">
            <g id="facilites">
                <circle class="st2" cx="420.25" cy="333.25" r="25.25">
                    <title>This is the first tooltip</title>
                </circle>
                <circle class="st2" cx="666.25" cy="470.25" r="25.25">
                    <title>This is the second tooltip</title>
                </circle>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Original (one tooltip for all of the SVG element)**

Try using a  element.
In the code below the user hovers the mouse over the svg and the  works as a tooltip.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <style>
        rect {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            opacity: 0;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <svg viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
            <g id="facilities">
                <circle class="st2" cx="420.25" cy="333.25" r="25.25"/>
                <circle class="st2" cx="666.25" cy="470.25" r="25.25"/>
            </g>
            <rect>
                <title>This is a single tooltip for the full SVG element</title>
            </rect>
        </svg>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

**Method 1. HTML/CSS Tooltip** 
Check this: [css tooltip hover](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden; //important
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1; /* put tooltip behind other layers */
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body>

    <div class="tooltip">Hover over me
      <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**Method 2. Javascript**
Search for your Js file if you are using some map API. There should be some code to initialize the map and all pin markers. For Google map it is something like this:

```
var latlng= new google.maps.LatLng(39.8282, -98.5795);  // center latitude and longitude 
var aa = new google.maps.LatLng(42.543214,-83.186111);  // a tooltip

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: latlng  // center latitude and longitude
}
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('your-canvas-id'), mapOptions);

markeraa = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: aa,
    map: map,
    title: 'Coolidge Highway in Troy, MI'  // hover and will show this text
});
```

All you have to do is to find the pin object and add a title line.